# In Python 3,a = 'linux!',b = 'linux!',why id(a) is not equal id(b)?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I use `a = 'linux!', b = 'linux!', c = 'linux', d='linux'`，Why does this happen?

```
 Python 3.6.3 (v3.6.3:2c5fed8, Oct  3 2017, 18:11:49) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> a = 'linux!'
>>> b = 'linux!'
>>> id(a)
2502413115552
>>> id(b)
2502414669112
>>> c = 'linux'
>>> d = 'linux'
>>> id(c)
2502413088616
>>> id(d)
2502413088616
>>>
```

Comment: Implementation details. If it ever matters, you're probably doing something wrong.

Comment: 'linux' is a legal identifier, 'linux!' is not.

Answer (score 4):

Python can choose when to reuse immutable objects with equal values.  The semantics of the language don't dictate whether a and b must be the same object or not.

Object reuse is an optimization with trade-offs.  I believe strings are reused if they are likely to be identifiers, but that might just be a rumor.